# Outputting php/MySQL Errors

Tags: php, mysql, echo

So, I am writing some php scripts for my website, and the INSERTing of data is not working. What I am wanting for now, and for future reference is a way to output the error as no syntax errors are already being outputted.

How would I echo out the error in my code?

```
echo "POSTed Data - ".$username.", ".$password."<br>";
$UserData_SQLInsert = "INSERT INTO UserData ( Username, Password ) VALUES ( ".$username.", ".$password." ) ";
if (mysql_query(UserData_SQLInsert)) {
  echo "INSERT INTO UserData - Succcessful.<br><br>";
}
else {
  echo "INSERT INTO UserData - Failed.<br><br>";
  mysql_query(UserData_SQLInsert) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: There might a problem with your query which doesn't show up as an error in the code. Could you show the code?

Comment: `mysql_query(UserData_SQLInsert)` is missing a `$`. All Variables need to start with a dollarsign in PHP.

Comment: Also, you want to read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Comment: Is your code a deliberate error and you want to output those errors? I'm not quite grasping something. I know where the errors are, just wondering on the first part of my question.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a few things going on: PHP errors, or MySQL errors, or just a non effective query (i.e. you didn't build the string properly or some such).

If it's PHP errors, you should have something in your PHP error log. You can also use `ini_set('display_errors',true);` to enable on-screen errors. This is usually helpful, but depending on the routing in your application, sometimes doesn't show everything. So check the PHP logs, too. Again depending on your framework/application, you could have applicaiton-specific errors logs catching the errors. Check with your vendor's documentation if this isn't a from-scratch project.

MySQL errors can be found using [mysqli_error](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php). Check if the query returns false and then use `mysqli_error` to spit out whatever the database said about it.

Also, as Gianluca suggested, you can use [var_dump](https://www.php.net/var_dump) to output your query in its entirely, which you can paste into MySQL Workbench or similar to review it more thoroughly.

Comment: My error is an SQL error, It is in this bit of code:

echo "POSTed Data - ".$username.", ".$password."<br>";

  $UserData_SQLInsert = "INSERT INTO UserData ( Username, Password ) VALUES ( ".$username.", ".$password." ) ";

  if (mysql_query(UserData_SQLInsert)) {
   echo "INSERT INTO UserData - Succcessful.<br><br>";
  } else {
   echo "INSERT INTO UserData - Failed.<br><br>";
   mysql_query(UserData_SQLInsert) or die(mysql_error());
  }

Comment: I think that Carpetsmoker spotted the biggest issue already, `UserData_SQLInsert` should be `$UserData_SQLInsert` (note the currency symbol $). If that's a verbatim copy-paste of your code, you're effectively sending the text 'UserData_SQLInsert' as your query.

Answer (score -1):

use the var_dump for any kind of doubt

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php